# Should a process always consume the same amount of memory if executed in the same way?

Tags: memory, process, memory-management, byte

Hi folks and thanks for your time in advance.

I'm currently extending our C# test framework to monitor the memory consumed by our application.  The intention being that a bug is potentially raised if the memory consumption significantly jumps on a new build as resources are always tight.

I'm using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessByName and then checking the PrivateMemorySize64 value.

During developing the new test, when using the same build of the application for consistency, I've seen it consume differing amounts of memory despite supposedly executing exactly the same code.

So my question is, if once an application has launched, fully loaded and in this case in it's idle state, hence in an identical state from run to run, can I expect the private bytes consumed to be identical from run to run?

I need to clarify that I can expect memory usage to be consistent as any degree of varience starts to reduce the effectiveness of the test as a degree of tolerance would need to be introduced, something I'd like to avoid.

So...

1) Should the memory usage be 100% consistent presuming the application is behaving consistenly? This was my expectation.

or

2) Is there is any degree of variance in the private byte usage returned by windows or in the memory it allocates when requested by an app?

Currently, if the answer is memory consumed should be consistent as I was expecteding, the issue lies in our app actually requesting a differing amount of memory.

Many thanks

H

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost everything in .NET uses the runtime's garbage collector, and when exactly it runs and how much memory it frees depends on a lot of factors, many of which are out of your hands. For example, when another program needs a lot of memory, and you have a lot of collectable memory at hand, the GC might decide to free it now, whereas when your program is the only one running, the GC heuristics might decide it's more efficient to let collectable memory accumulate a bit longer. So, short answer: No, memory usage is not going to be 100% consistent.

OTOH, if you have really big differences between runs (say, a few megabytes on one run vs. half a gigabyte on another), you should get suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for the quick repsonses from both yourself and Leppie :)

Comment: The app under test is written in C\C++, just my framework is in C#. That being the case, even though the .NET GC isn't being used it sounds like I can still expect to see difference due to memory fragmentation etc?

Comment: Yes. Memory fragmentation, thread scheduling, disk usage, swapping, those can all effect your program's reported memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is deterministic (like all embedded programs should be), then yes. In an OS environment you are very unlikely to get the same figures due to memory fragmentation and numerous other factors.

**Update:**

Just noted this a C# app, so no, but the numbers should be relatively close (+/- 10% or less).